# PAM conversation error in running shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script in which I run this follow:

```
cd system_xml
sudo find . -name "*.xml" | sudo xargs gzip
```

system_xml contains about 60K xml files. I am trying to find and replace all the original xml files with the gziped version of that file.

However about 3 minutes after running this file, I get the following error:

```
PAM conversation error
```

Comment: A bit of google search yielded me with this, https://support.software.dell.com/authentication-services/kb/35792

Comment: Can you try to execute just one `sudo` command?

Comment: @Inian thanks, I found the same link but I was/am still uncertain what PAM conversation error is. Perhaps I should have rephrased the question better.

Comment: @JoseRaulBarreras thanks, I ran that command and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I changed the script to do the following:

```
sudo bash;
find -type f -name '*.xml' | xargs gzip
```

and for whatever reason it worked. I'm still not comfortable to accept this answer without some explanation as to why this worked.

Can you not have 2 sudo programs executing in a pipe? I know this is the case for nohup